# Trying to understand Knuth's algorithm for permutations

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, pointers, knuth

I was recently instructed in one of my algorithm classes to use Knuth's algorithm to create permutations stored in a malloc'd array.

Here is the setup:

array is a pointer to a malloced array holding the permutation. It is intially storing n values, each position holding the index + 1.

So if n was 10, the array would initially be:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

The "rand" variable holds some variable from 1 to n. (In this example, 1-10).

Swap is supposed to be a function that does a bit-exclusive OR swap (XOR).

The end result is supposed to be some permutation of 1-n.

So [5, 6, 2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 3, 10, 9] would be valid as one possible permutation.

However, [1, 1, 5, 7, 8, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6] would not be valid, since it's not a permutation. It has duplicates.

But I can't make heads or tails of this code we were told to use:

```
for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    swap(&array[i], &a[rand]);
}
```

So we start off on the second element of the array. (i = 1)

We then attempt to XOR two paramenters:

First: &array[i]

That is the address of a pointer to the malloced array. (A double pointer, right?)

And the second parameter is the exact same thing. An address of a pointer to the malloced array.

How and why the heck am I supposed to do XOR on addresses?

What am I not understanding?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: So your question is basically "what does `&array[i]` mean?"?  If so, the answer is "the address of the `i`-th element in `array`".

Comment: You mention `swap` (and apparently it uses `xor`) but fail to show this function. While a XOR swap is a good way to do it, it is *by no means* part of the algorithm you are asking about. Any regular way of swapping ought to work.

Comment: C parameters are always pass-by-value, so the subroutine `swap` cannot change the parameters passed back in the calling routine. However, by passing the address of those parameters, the `swap` routine can reference the addresses and change the values at those addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, swap is not supposed to do a bitwise exclusive or.  It's supposed to swap.

Usually, that's written:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;
}
```

But there's a trick using XOR that doesn't require an extra variable.  You can implement swap like this:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a^=*b;
    *b^=*a;
    *a^=*b;
}
```

Which is probably what someone meant by doing an XOR in swap.

Secondly, rand has to range from 0 to i, not 1 to n, of you want an unbiased random permutation.

Given rand(x) returns a number in [0,x], you want something like this:

```
for (int i=n-1; i>0; --i)
{
    j = rand(i);
    if (i!=j)
    {
        swap(&array[i],&array[j]);
    }
}
```

The way it works is simple:  for each array[i], it chooses an element randomly *from the ones that haven't already been picked*.

Comment: Ah! I remember this! He said something about using XOR, but it only worked in some certain circumstance. When A does NOT equal B, if I remember right.

Comment: The XOR swap doesn't work when a and b refer to the same object.  Then the first line does array[i]^=array[i], which is the same as array[i]=0.  Don't use the XOR swap.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add. So I'm swapping the value at array[i] with the array[rand]? So if I got the random number 6 first, array[1] would be 6, and array[6] would be 1?

Comment: yes, but rand has to go from 0 to i.  So when i==1, rand has to be either 0 or 1

Comment: bah, and you have to run i backwards... I'll just put the correct one in the answer

Comment: Oddly enough, the swap function is giving me issues. Right where it's declared it's throwing an error, saying that there should be a semicolon/punctuation before after the & in swap(int &a, int &b).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were using C++.  Fixing...